# Does HTML snapshot required by googlebot need to be styled

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, googlebot

To make an ajax site web crawlable by googlebot, it requries that your website send back a HTML snapshot when a page with the _escaped_fragment variable set. (for more info see [here](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/))

Does this HTML snapshot need to be styled correctly, i.e. does googlebot use the snapshot to give a preview of your site (as you see on the search results page). I ask as some of my pages use javascript to correctly resize images dynamically as this cant by done in the CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to take a snapshot of the page as it is rendered on the client side, then it might make sense to generate these snapshots with a headless browser such as HtmlUnit if you are using Java or php. It may be less work to try and move your image processing to the server side if feasible.

While it is unlikely that your snapshots will be used as a preview (all the #! crawled sites I checked all said "No preview available"), it could technically be considered "cloaking" if you have differences in your snapshot and in your served page. I doubt Google would get mad over a few CSS differences but it is worth noting.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate HTMLUnit with PHP - my understanding is that it is written in java

Comment: Take a look at [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). They've also got a guide to setting up Eclipse for PHP and the java bridge.

Comment: One quest: HTML snapshot means providing them with complete HTML after processing the JS/Ajax. right?